# Notification not showing when app is closed : Android

Tags: java, android, xml, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I am new to android development ,
I am creating an app in which you can mark your attendance,
So when attendance is low it will send a notification,
I write the following code

```
private void setup(final String keys, final int uid, final String x) {
    final int[] uid0 = {uid};
    br = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override

        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {

            NotificationCompat.Builder notf;
            uid0[0] += 1;
            notf = new NotificationCompat.Builder(see.this);
            notf.setAutoCancel(true);
            notf.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            notf.setTicker("Your attendance is low!!");
            notf.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
            notf.setContentTitle("Your "+keys+" attendance is low !!");

            notf.setContentText("It is "+x+" %");
            Intent inte = new Intent(see.this,see.class);
            PendingIntent penin= PendingIntent.getActivity(see.this,0,inte,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            notf.setContentIntent(penin);
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nm.notify(uid,notf.build());

        }

    };

    registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("com.ajaypilaniya.omg"));

    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("com.ajaypilaniya.omg"),
            0 );

    am = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));

}
```

This is the setup function which define notification properties.
In class i have these lines

```
final long ONE_SECOND = 1000;

final long TWENTY_SECONDS = ONE_SECOND * 10;

PendingIntent pi;

BroadcastReceiver br;

AlarmManager am;

setup(keys,uid,kk);
                am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
                        TWENTY_SECONDS, pi);
```

In android manifest i added these lines

```
 <user-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<user-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>`
```

But when i close the app then it is not showing notification after 10 seconds, So how to do that?
Somewhere I read that we need add code for broadcast receiver in manifest but i don't have any idea how to do that?